# Regex IsOne vs Containing

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am writing a PostGres `check`in order to constrain a text field to one of 4 different values. I am avoiding `Enum` type on purpose as it has been known to cause issues.

I seem to have more of a "contains" instead of has to be one of these.

```
ALTER TABLE registrations
  ADD CONSTRAINT proper_confirmation_status CHECK (confirmation_status::
text ~* '^(Unconfirmed|Confirmed|Rejected|NotApplicable)'::text);
```

So:

1. The word should be one of those 4 without any additional characters (start or finish).
2. The check should be case sensitive
3. Currently `confirmdddddd` is validated correctly, but `confirmedSSSS`

Comment: If the whole field should be equal to your `|`-separated values, use `^` and `$`: `'^(Unconfirmed|Confirmed|Rejected|NotApplicable)$'`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  I tried your suggestion but it fails (see #3 above). I just realized the postgres operator `~*` may be the reason why it is `matching/contains` vs `equals`. Adding postgres tag to question.

Comment: The `$` must have dealt with Point 3 OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `IN` operator instead of regex.

```
ALTER TABLE registrations
  ADD CONSTRAINT proper_confirmation_status CHECK (
    confirmation_status::text IN ('Unconfirmed', 'Confirmed', 'Rejected', 'NotApplicable'));
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `~` (case senstive) instead of `~*` (case intenstive)
2. The regex should be `^(....)$` (match whole string)
3. The syntax looks a bit weired, does it work?

   ```
   ALTER TABLE registrations
     ADD CONSTRAINT proper_confirmation_status CHECK
       (confirmation_status::text ~ '^(Unconfirmed|Confirmed|Rejected|NotApplicable)$');
   ```